# Unable to set up razorpay payment gateway for ios flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

I have successfully implemented razorpay plugin for android. But I couldn’t find a way to run on iOS simulator throwing the error.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[46285]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x212eb7130) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10679c2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[46285]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x212eb7180) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10679c318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/q1/bn7h2y0j58ngn7rb80fr1yhh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.u4wUAC/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirOLb14O/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    ld: warning: all bitcode will be dropped because '/Users/devytpl/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built without bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    ld: warning: all bitcode will be dropped because '/Users/devytpl/Downloads/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built without bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.
    /Users/devytpl/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.3.2/ios/Classes/RazorpayDelegate.swift:2:8: error: module 'Razorpay' was created for incompatible target arm64-apple-ios10.0: /Users/devytpl/Dev/Applications/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule
    import Razorpay
           ^
    /Users/devytpl/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.3.2/ios/Classes/RazorpayDelegate.swift:2:8: error: module 'Razorpay' was created for incompatible target arm64-apple-ios10.0: /Users/devytpl/Dev/Applications/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule
    import Razorpay
           ^
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/devytpl/Dev/Applications/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/devytpl/Dev/Applications/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/q1/bn7h2y0j58ngn7rb80fr1yhh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.u4wUAC/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirOLb14O/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Module 'Razorpay' was created for incompatible target arm64-apple-ios10.0: /Users/devytpl/Dev/Applications/ios/Pods/razorpay-pod/Pod/Razorpay.framework/Modules/Razorpay.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule
/Users/devytpl/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/razorpay_flutter-1.3.2/ios/Classes/RazorpayDelegate.swift:1:7
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

**Flutter Version: 3.0.5**

**Target Platform: 10.0**